# FXML TableView "Class fxmlPerson does not support property "bestellnr"

Tags: java, tableview, fxml, scenebuilder

So I'm currently trying to implement a GUI for an online-shop (assignment for university) and I'm stuck at the table which lists all current orders. 
The GUI is based on an FXML-Application.
My TableView is as follows:

```
<TableView fx:id="tableView" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="1250.0" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
   <columns>
      <TableColumn text="Bestellnr.">
         <cellValueFactory>
            <PropertyValueFactory property="bestellnr" />
         </cellValueFactory>
      </TableColumn>
[7 more columns like that, but with different properties]
   </columns>
   <items>
      <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
         <Person bestellnr="0001" kundennr="0000" kundenname="John Smith" summe="1000" lieferstatus="gesendet" bestelldatum="03.12.1291" liefertermin="05.12.1291" bezahlt="yes" />
      </FXCollections>
   </items>
</TableView>
```

The properties of the class "Person" are SimpleStringProperties

```
    private final SimpleStringProperty bestellnr = new SimpleStringProperty("");
    private final SimpleStringProperty kundennr = new SimpleStringProperty("");
    private final SimpleStringProperty kundenname = new SimpleStringProperty("");
    private final SimpleStringProperty summe = new SimpleStringProperty("");
    private final SimpleStringProperty lieferstatus = new SimpleStringProperty("");
    private final SimpleStringProperty bestelldatum = new SimpleStringProperty("");
    private final SimpleStringProperty liefertermin = new SimpleStringProperty("");
    private final SimpleStringProperty bezahlt = new SimpleStringProperty("");
```

I also added getter- and setter-methods to these SimpleStringProperties:

```
   public String getBestellNr() {
        return bestellnr.get();
    }

    public void setBestellNr(String fName) {
        bestellnr.set(fName);
    }

    public String getKundenNr() {
        return kundennr.get();
    }

    public void setKundenNr(String fName) {
        kundennr.set(fName);
    }

    public String getKundenName() {
        return kundenname.get();
    }

    public void setKundenName(String fName) {
        kundenname.set(fName);
    }

    public String getSumme() {
        return summe.get();
    }

    public void setSumme(String fName) {
        summe.set(fName);
    }

    public String getLieferStatus() {
        return lieferstatus.get();
    }

    public void setLieferStatus(String fName) {
        lieferstatus.set(fName);
    }

    public String getBestellDatum() {
        return bestelldatum.get();
    }

    public void setBestellDatum(String fName) {
        bestelldatum.set(fName);
    }

    public String getLieferTermin() {
        return liefertermin.get();
    }

    public void setLieferTermin(String fName) {
        liefertermin.set(fName);
    }

    public String getBezahlt() {
        return bezahlt.get();
    }

    public void setBezahlt(String fName) {
        bezahlt.set(fName);
    }
```

Now everytime I try to run the project, I get the error "Class fxmlPerson does not support property "bestellnr".

I based this program on this tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/fxml_get_started/fxml_tutorial_intermediate.htm and it works. But as soon as I start adding the additional columns I get this error.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Have you added getters and setters for these properties?  (See http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/fxml_get_started/fxml_tutorial_intermediate.htm#sthref10).  If so, please edit your question to include them.

Comment: @LukeWoodward Yes I have, as you can see in the edited post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property names being used in your FXML file do not match the method names of your getters and setters.

A property with name `bestellnr` must correspond to methods with names `getBestellnr` and `setBestellnr`.  Your methods have names `getBestellNr` and `setBestellNr`.  The capitalisation of the letter `N` is the difference.

To get from a property name to a getter or setter method name, you capitalise the first letter and put `get` or `set` on the front.

Change the property `bestellnr` in your FXML to `bestellNr`, or change your getter and setter methods to `getBestellnr` and `setBestellnr`.  Repeat this process for other properties where the property names and method names don't match.

Comment: Thank you so much!! It worked. I can't believe I wasted hours to find that easy mistake...